# How to add marker MOVING animation in react-google-maps?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

How can I implement Marker moving animation in React app. I have used [react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps) for Google Maps.

I am going through the documentation for the library and Google Maps API. There is an option of offset in Google Maps API. But I am not looking for that.

The app will be receiving updated coordinates via a socket.io server. And as soon as the coordinates arrive the marker needs to be moved, like the Uber app.

There is an open issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/154) which is not closed yet.

Currently, I am able to move the markers on the coordinates updates, but without animation.

Sample code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Socket from 'socket.io-client';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    GoogleMap,
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap,
    Marker
} from 'react-google-maps';

import { googleMapsUrl, socketUrl } from '../../../config/constants';

const io = Socket(socketUrl('dev'));

class GoogleMaps extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            defaultCenter: {
                clientId: "FAKE_CLIENT_ID",
                imei:     "FAKE_IMEI_NUMBER",
                lat:      28.554907,
                lng:      77.554385,
                name:     "FAKE_NAME"
            },
            defaultZoom:  10,
            movingMarker: [],
            AllMarkers:   []
        };
        this.pullDataFromSocket = this.pullDataFromSocket.bind(this);
        this.createMovingMarker = this.createMovingMarker.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.pullDataFromSocket();
    }

    pullDataFromSocket() {
        const pathname = this.props.location.pathname.replace(/\//, '');

        io.on('data', data => {
            const markerCoordinates = data.devicedatalist.map(ds => {
                // Some valude modification
                return {
                    ...ds
                }
            });

            const movingMarker = this.state.movingMarker;
            movingMarker.push(markerCoordinates[0]);

            this.setState({
                AllMarkers:    markerCoordinates,
                defaultCenter: markerCoordinates[0],
                movingMarker
            });
        });
    }

    createMovingMarker() {
        let MarkerLocation = this.state.defaultCenter;
        if (this.state.movingMarker.length > 1) {
            /**
            * Setting the marker to the updated new location
            */
            MarkerLocation = this.state.movingMarker[this.state.movingMarker.length - 1];
        }

        return (
            <Marker
                position={MarkerLocation}
            >
            </Marker>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <GoogleMap
                defaultZoom={this.state.defaultZoom}
                center={this.state.defaultCenter}
            >
                {this.createMovingMarker()}
            </GoogleMap>
        )
    };
}

const MapWrapper = withRouter(
    withScriptjs(
        withGoogleMap(GoogleMaps)
    )
);

export default () => {
    return (
        <MapWrapper
            googleMapURL={googleMapsUrl()}
            loadingElement={<div />}
            mapElement={<div style={{height: '100vh'}} />}
            containerElement={<div />}
        />
    )
};
```

Comment: Did you manage to do this? how? I am using react-google-maps/api